# Powershell - Create a shortcut with a file as an argument

Tags: powershell, shortcut-file

I am trying to automate shortcut creation in windows in a powershell script.  I created a function to make this easier since I need to pass a similar shortcut in a few places when the script runs, but any time I try to pass in an argument to open a specific file, the Arguments field get dropped.

If I do:

```
Function MakeAShortcut($RunPath, $Arguments, $ShortcutName, $ShortcutLocation){
    $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutLocation + $ShortcutName + '.lnk')
    $Shortcut.Targetpath = -join($RunPath,"\Notepad++.exe")
    $Shortcut.Arguments = "C:\tests\testfile.txt"
    $Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $RunPath
    $Shortcut.IconLocation = -join($RunPath,"\Notepad++.exe",", 0")
    $Shortcut.Save()

    Write-Host "`nShortcut created at "$ShortcutLocation$ShortcutName'.lnk'
}

$DefaultFileName = "C:\tests\testfile.txt"
$Runapppath = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++"

MakeAShortcut $Runapppath $DefaultFileName "ShortcutTEST" "c:\tests\"
```

Then the script will output a shortcut that properly runs the program (in this case Notepad++) and the default file to load with the shortcut (testfile.txt).

However, if I do:

```
Function MakeAShortcut($RunPath, $Arguments, $ShortcutName, $ShortcutLocation){
    $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutLocation + $ShortcutName + '.lnk')
    $Shortcut.Targetpath = -join($RunPath,"\Notepad++.exe")
    $Shortcut.Arguments = $Arguments
    $Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $RunPath
    $Shortcut.IconLocation = -join($RunPath,"\Notepad++.exe",", 0")
    $Shortcut.Save()

    Write-Host "`nShortcut created at "$ShortcutLocation$ShortcutName'.lnk'
}

$DefaultFileName = "C:\tests\testfile.txt"
$Runapppath = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++"

MakeAShortcut $Runapppath $DefaultFileName "ShortcutTEST" "c:\tests\"
```

Then it just discards the `$Shortcut.Arguments` field completely (regardless if I feed the `$DefaultFileName` as a variable or explicit string) and creates a shortcut that only runs the program (in this case Notepad++)

I have tried triple-quoting the value passing into the `$DefaultFileName` position.  I have tried accentuating the characters such as the colon etc.  If I pass in something in addition (Example: `$Shortcut.Arguments = '-noPlugins ' + $Arguments` it will append just the addition (-noPlugins).  I have tried using a different variable name other than `$Arguments`.  I have tried doing `[string]$Arguments` in the parameters declaration and `$Arguments.ToString()` in the usage.

<s>Can you please help me know what I am doing wrong?</s>

EDIT - Thanks to TessellatingHeckler for pointing out to me that it was something with the computers I was actually doing this script on that was preventing this.  Now to find out why...

Comment: Works for me. Copied your second codeblock, changed `c:\tests` to a folder that exists on my computer, and I get a shortcut for `"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" C:\tests\testfile.txt`. What environment are you using? OS version, PS version, and have you closed/reopened PS between runs just to check nothing is hanging around from a previous run?

Comment: Well then color me dumb.  I had closed ISE / rebooted etc on the computers I was working on this script on, but in testing this on my home computer just now it did work.  Guess it's time to track down what stupid setting in my main workstation and laptop (both) is causing this.  Thank you for your help and patience with an apparent waste of a question.

Answer (score 1):

This was just occurring for me and I found your post looking for a solution (which I didn't find anywhere).  Making your line the equivalent to this ended up fixing it for me:

```
$Shortcut.Arguments = [string]$Arguments
```

So for some reason a cast is needed to assign the variable the correct type.