# Can Powershell process code in a BAT file?

Tags: powershell

I want to place PowerShell code in a BAT File and start the BAT file from the Windows explorer by double-click. Powershell shall execute BAT as PowerShell script. The intention is show in this example "a.bat":

```
@rem = ""
powershell -NoLogo -File %0
goto :eof
""

"Greetings from Powershell" | Out-Host
```

But Powershell insist on .ps1 file extension:

> Processing -File '.\a.bat' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.

I know, I can fold the script from the BAT file in one line and pass it with the -Command option to Powershell. But this makes it unreadable.

I could also store the Powershell code in a .ps1 file. But a double-click will open it in notepad instead of executing the code.

Is there any way to fold both (BAT and Powershell script) in one file?

**Edit:** There shall be only the BAT file to be double-clicked by the user. That's why I don't have a BAT|PS1 pair or shortcuts for any of the BAT files. 
<sup>The minimal reproducible example doesn't include the possibility to have several BAT files.</sup>

Comment: Why not just starting your script (with arguments) from a shortcut? Here ([Powershell - Create a shortcut with a file as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50126373/1701026)) is even an example how you might create such a shortcut automatically.

Comment: Use cmd.exe : cmd.exe %0

Comment: @iRon The idea is to have a file that can be double-clicked in an arbitrary folder.

Comment: you can change the default double click action of .ps1 files to not open the file but execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is closely related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2609985/45375), though your particular use case involves a *simplification*:

- **You do not need to support *pass-through arguments***, given that running batch files by *double-clicking* from File Explorer (or the desktop) doesn't allow for passing arguments to the executable (batch file) being invoked.
- **More work** is needed in order **to also support pass-through arguments** (that is, if your batch should also be callable *from the command line*, with arguments) and to do so *robustly* you do need the `-File` CLI parameter, which in turn requires creating a *temporary copy* of the batch file *with a `.ps1` extension*, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063524/45375) (of mine) to the linked post.

**Robust solution *without* pass-through argument support:**

```bash
<# ::
@echo off & setlocal
set "__thisBatchFile=%~f0"
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c "iex (gc -Raw -LiteralPath \"%~f0\")"
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
#>

# Paste arbitrary PowerShell code here.
# Use $env:__thisBatchFile to refer to this file's full path.
"Hello from the PowerShell part of hybrid batch file `"$env:__thisBatchFile`""
```

- `<# ... #>` is seen as a block comment *by PowerShell* and therefore ignored.
- `cmd.exe` ignores the first line, `<# ::`, but executes the following ones up to and including the `exit /b` call - it doesn't care about what comes after.
- `set "__thisBatchFile=%~f0"` creates an environment variable containing the batch file's own full path (`%~f0`), which the PowerShell code can reference as `$env:__thisBatchFile`

  - It won't matter in the double-click scenario, but the `setlocal` part of `@echo off & setlocal` ensures that this aux. variable doesn't linger if the batch file is called from an interactive `cmd.exe` session (Command Prompt).
- The call to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, breaks down as follows:

  - `-NoProfile` suppresses loading of PowerShell's [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), which can speed up the call and makes for a more predictable execution environment.
  - `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` bypasses the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) to ensure that your PowerShell code predictably executes.
  - Note:

    - This assumes that you fully control or implicitly trust not just the PowerShell code in the batch file itself, but also any outside code it calls.
    - If a GPO-based execution policy that prevents execution of local scripts altogether or unsigned local scripts is in effect, it can *not* be overridden with `-ExecutionPolicy`.
    - However, as long as the PowerShell code placed directly in the batch file doesn't call `.ps1` files or *script* modules, that won't matter.
  - `-c` is the alias of `-Command`, which causes all subsequent arguments to be interpreted as PowerShell code.
  - `iex` is the built-in alias of [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (which is *usually* to be avoided), to which the full text of the batch file (obtained via `gc`, the built-in alias of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)  and its `-Raw` switch) is passed for evaluation.
- `exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` passes `powershell.exe`'s process exit code through, as the batch file's exit code.

---

As noted in the comments, an **alternative** is to redefine the file type for `.ps1` files that double-clicking them *executes* them, instead of the default behavior of *opening them for editing*.

- That said, users may not expect this behavior, which can lead to unwanted execution of scripts.
- If you still want to do it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58245206/45375) for a (nontrivial) solution.